A romantic drama about a terminally ill woman falls in love
I'm looking for a drama, romance movie. I'm 100% positive this movie was aired in 2000~2010 because I saw it in 2010/2009.
The movie is about a terminally ill (some kind of asthma like sickness) blonde / light brown hair woman who falls in love with a handsome man. They move in together at his house, not married. They write some kind of rules, a rule everyday. I think that at the end of the movie they print lots copies of their rules list, drive and the copies fly out of the car window.
Country: USA, language: English, not dubbed
This movie had a message about love.

Country of release?  Language?  Dubbed?

Dono the country pretty sure usa but not positive english language, not dubbed

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.

Jack and Jill vs. the World 2008

Jack (Prinze Jr.) is a thirty-something New York City advertising executive, living a life forged from routine. He is successful and stylish... and extremely bored. Jack meets Jill (Manning) by chance on a rooftop. Jill is looking for an apartment and asks Jack for directions. Jack suggests Jill's name for an ad shoot. Later he drives Jill to her apartment and realizes the neighborhood may not be all that safe. He helps Jill move out of her place and the two move in together by week's end. The pair pieces together a playful manifesto of "rules to live by." Jack's best friend and business partner, George (Stebbings), notices a more playful side to Jack's usual cynicism, and wants to meet the cause.
Jill's free-spirited nature causes some friction, however. When her long absences go unexplained, Jack forces Jill to confess that her disappearances are a result of the treatment she needs for cystic fibrosis, an ultimately terminal illness. Jack is furious with Jill for violating their pact of honesty, and they break up.
A talk with his father Norman (Forster) incites Jack to find Jill. Jack tracks down her wacky friend, Lucy (Parise), and pleads his case. Convinced that he truly loves Jill, Lucy admits that Jill is catching a Greyhound bus cross-country to Hollywood. Jack reevaluates his life, and just as he quits his job, a bomb threat is called in at his work. Jack goes outside and George tells him that the bomb threat was called in by someone who wants to fight ugliness. Jack realizes that the culprit has to be Jill. The two make up, and with their new dog in tow, they hit the highway... with no destination in sight except for a life together.





I think you are referring to Sweet November with Keanu Reeves and Charlize Theron. She is terminally ill and she has this rules and she helps Keanu Reeves's character to enjoy life. He is an ad executive and always on the go. Basically opposite attracts kinda movie.
